# MAUI Webview target="_blank" href redirects not working on android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, maui

I have an MAUI app that is essentially a `WebView` that hosts a wordpress website.
My problem is that whenever I try to load an external link it will simply not load the "href" redirect... It works fine on Windows and iOS devices, but not in android.

EDIT: The href is a "_blank" target.

Is there a specific permission I need in the manifest?

In case it helps, here is the code for the page:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MYAPPNAME.EnglishPage" 
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGrey">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                         Spacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="8">
            <Button Text="Go Back" TextColor="DarkSlateGray" BackgroundColor="White"/>
            <Button Text="Change Language" x:Name="ChangeLangBtn" TextColor="DarkSlateGray" BackgroundColor="White"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <WebView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                     Source="https://example.com"
                     x:Name="WebView"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is the manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="2">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="MYAPPNAME"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to handle redirects to `_blank` targets in a WebView by keeping them in the same window/view, I had to create a custom renderer, but don't worry, you can just copy-paste the code and it will work perfectly :) .

1. Create a folder called `Controls` inside `Platforms/Android`, then create a class file, I called it `MltWebViewClientRenderer.cs`.
   Paste this inside the file:

```cs
    public class MltWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MltWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new MltWebViewClient());
            global::Android.Webkit.WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public class MltWebViewClient : global::Android.Webkit.WebViewClient
    {
        public MltWebViewClient()
        {
        }

        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(global::Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        {
            view.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(false);
            view.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
            
            view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

            view.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

            return base.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }
    }
```

The above code basically allows access to the `Settings` of the `WebView`.

2. In the `MauiProgram.cs`, you need to add some services to the builder, as such:

```cs
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                })
                .UseMauiCompatibility()
                .ConfigureMauiHandlers(x =>
                {
#if ANDROID
                    x.AddCompatibilityRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(Platforms.Android.Controls.MltWebViewRenderer));
#endif
                });
            return builder.Build();
```

The above only invokes our custom renderer if we are on Android.

Note: This solution only works for Android API versions 24 and above.

Answer (score 3):

I have done a sample to test the webview in the android, it can open the href in the website successfully.

So you can check the href you want open is http or not. For the android api higher than 27, you need to declare the `android:usesCleartextTraffic` as true in the AndroidManifest.xml, such as:

```
<manifest ...>
  <application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
    ...
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

You can also try to load another website in your webview to test.

**Edit**

Refer to this [native android case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009995/android-webview-links-to-same-window-with-target-blank-to-open-new-window) and the [custom webview handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322225/maui-net-modifies-the-layout-of-the-website-inside-the-webview), you can just try to use the handler to override the `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` method to do that.

Comment: my href is "_blank", and it does not work even after adding the code you sent me

Comment: But the href usually is a url such as `<link rel="xxx" href="https:...">`. @YaRmgl

Comment: Yes but in my case the <a> tags point to a third party website in a "_blank" page. I need that new page opened in the WebView

Comment: I can't understand how is the href showing in your project clearly. Do you mean the same condition in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009995/android-webview-links-to-same-window-with-target-blank-to-open-new-window)? If so, you may need use the custom renderer or handler for the android platform.@YaRmgl

Comment: No I want it to open in the same window like it does on iOS

Comment: You can try to use the custom render or the handler and override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method to load the href by your self just like the op did in the link I provided. @YaRmgl

Comment: I have no way of going to settings for a control, I am kind of lost, could you edit your answer with the proper steps to create a custom renderer for this task? thanks

Comment: You can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322225/maui-net-modifies-the-layout-of-the-website-inside-the-webview) which shows how to custom the webview in the maui. Just override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading instead of the OnElementChanged method. @YaRmgl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248959/discussion-between-yarmgl-and-liyun-zhang-msft).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. @YaRmgl answer worked for fixing the links but seemed to prevent the WebView.Navigated event from firing. Adapting the solution to the MAUI handler seemed to fix the issue and keep the WebView.Navigated event working.

1. Create a folder called Controls inside Platforms/Android, then create a class file called AndroidWebViewHandler.cs. Paste this inside the file:

```
public class AndroidWebViewHandler : WebViewHandler
    {
        protected override void ConnectHandler(global::Android.Webkit.WebView platformView)
        {
            platformView.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(false);
            platformView.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;

            platformView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            base.ConnectHandler(platformView);            
        }
    }
```

2. In the `MauiProgram.cs` configure the handler

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
    {
        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
    })
    .UseMauiCompatibility()
    .ConfigureMauiHandlers(x =>
    {
#if ANDROID
    x.AddHandler<WebView, Platforms.Android.Controls.AndroidWebViewHandler>();
#endif
    });
return builder.Build();
```